# Creating a dynamic swagger for an Elasticsearch API

Tags: elasticsearch, swagger, elasticsearch-5, faceted-search, openapi

I want to create a dynamic **swagger** of an **elasticsearch API** since the response returned by Api is unexpected because it contains **facets** and I would like to know if there is way to generate the **swagger automatically** through **elasticsearch**.

Answer (score 2):

It's not possible at the moment. It needs  https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/25152 to be implemented first.

Comment: It looks like they closed the issue without implementing it :(